# Center OK button in QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible to center the OK button in a QDialog?

```
class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(200, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.Window
                                         | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        QBtn = QDialogButtonBox.Ok

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        message = QLabel(text)
        self.layout.addWidget(message)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

The dialog shows **only** the OK button and I would like it to be centerd instead of right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [`centerButtons`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#centerButtons-prop) property:

```
    self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(True)
```

Also consider that by default widgets are added to a layout by trying to fill all the available space in the layout "cell". Specifying the alignment results in aligning the widget by using its size hint as maximum space.

So, an alternative is to change to:

```
    self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Comment: That won't change the alignment of the buttons inside a QDialogButtonBox. And in any case, the OP is using a *vertical* layout. I would suggest using [QDialogButtonBox.setCenterButtons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#centerButtons-prop) instead.

Comment: @ekhumoro Right, I forgot about that property. That said, setting the alignment should limit the used space of the button box no matter the layout direction and based on the minimum size hint of the buttons, thus centering it anyway, but I admit that I only checked it on Linux.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case, setting the layout aligment will also work as a side-effect because the button-box does not have a fixed/minimum width (i.e. one that is wider than the contained buttons). For the general case, it would seem more robust to explicitly centre the buttons.